# Почему я не могу обратиться к полю класса-наследника в Java?

Tags: java

Есть два класса, один наследник другого:

```
public class myClass1 {}

public class myClass2 extends myClass1 {
    public int x;
}
```

Почему, записав в переменную типа myClass1 ссылку на объект myClass2 я не могу обратиться к полю **x** принадлежащему myClass2?

```
public class Go {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myClass1 c1 = new myClass2();
        c1.x = 10; //ОШИБКА
    }
}
```

Comment: НЕ смотря на то, что в дубликате речь о списках, смысл тот же

Answer (score 3):

Простой ответ: потому что в классе-предке `myClass1`, к которому относится переменная `c1`, поле `x` "отсутствует".

Так как в Java применяется статическая сильная типизация, то есть компилятор во время компиляции "не знает", что переменной `c1`, объявленной с типом `myClass1`, может быть присвоен экземпляр какого-то из подклассов.  Также компилятор не может быть уверенным, что во время выполнения может быть присвоен экземпляр другого подкласса.

То есть, объявив переменную с классом-предком `myClass1`, программист согласился, что свойства/методы, определённые в подклассах, его не интересуют.

Если *очень надо* обратиться к свойству/методу подкласса через ссылку на класс-предок, можно воспользоваться операцией приведения типа, которая может выбросить исключение `ClassCastException`, для защиты от которого понадобится проверить тип, например при помощи `instanceof`:

```java
if (c1 instanceof myClass2) {
    ((myClass2) c1).x = 10;
}
```